# Set a default iteration path for a work item type on TFS

Tags: tfs, iteration, tfs-workitem

I try to tune my Team Foundation 2005 work items.
We have 5 iterations paths in the "Bug" work item type.

I would like it to default to a specific value, for example Iterations.Iteration2
I tried to add a DEFAULT rule in the work item type editor but couldn't set the iteration path.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error with TFS 2010 when I try to set a default rule for a work item type for a default iteration path.

It seems the rules engine for work items unfortunately doesn't allow this (as explained by [this](http://blogs.socha.com/2009/01/tf26062-error-for-area-and-iteration.html) post and others I've seen around).

Answer (score 0):

Create a Work Item Template.

If you're using VS, you'll need the [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx).  If you're using the web interface, [the feature is already built-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/comments/8506227.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Richard

Thanks for your answer. 

Actually I already have the VS Power Tools. I used it to configure my work items templates. I managed to set default values to other fields but not the "iteration path".

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe it was a bug in the VS2005 version of the power tools that's since been fixed.